# DecimalFormat not giving proper output in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and have gotten to a section teaching about different Java Utilities and number formatting. However, my formatting is not working the same as they say it should in the book. My code looks like this:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Lessons {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double d = 7.1348759272948202842847;

    System.out.printf("%15e %n", d);

    NumberFormat cashFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.println(cashFormat.format(d));

    double e = 14.9;
    double f = 16.09805938020001;
    double g = 12346;

    DecimalFormat Dec_Format = new DecimalFormat("##0.##E0");

    System.out.println(Dec_Format.format(e));
    System.out.println(Dec_Format.format(f));
    System.out.println(Dec_Format.format(g));
}
```

In the book example, it says that 12345 formatted with "##0.##E0" is "12.3E3". The output I'm receiving is "12.345E3".

The output that I'm receiving makes sense, but since it doesn't match the book, I'm not sure if it's an error in the book or if I'm doing something wrong.

Is this the normal output?